# Android: DeviceAdmin Application: Unable to start activity to add device admin

Tags: android, admin

I was following the example code for the Device Admin app. My attempts to start activity that enables the user to add a device admin app has failed. The following is the code which I use to try and start this.

```
public class DeviceAdminTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ComponentName deviceAdminReceiver = new ComponentName(this, TestAdminReceiver.class);
        Intent i = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        i.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdminReceiver);
        i.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "My Explanantion");

//        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        try{
            startActivity(i);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the code of the Receiver...

```
public class TestAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "On Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return ("You are about to disable device admin");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "On Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "On Password Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the manifest...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.zeezulander.admintest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.zeezulander.admintest.DeviceAdminTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".TestAdminReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" android:label="Test Admin">        
            <meta-data android:resource="@xml/admin_data" android:name="adminMetaData"/>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

I do not get an error even. My Activity starts, but nothing happens beyond, no error even.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with the layout.  If you're not getting an error, then it isn't crashing, and if it isn't crashing then the only thing that could be wrong is the display (layout).

Answer (score -2):

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd"));
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, adminReceiver);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "To use all features activate it.");
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
```

Comment: You do not even explain?

Comment: It opens DevicePolicyManager even it is already activated..
Usually DevicePolicyManager does not open once it is activate it via programming code.
Now You may open it even it is already activate.